# Subclassed edit control accepts dot eventhough it shouldn't

Tags: c++, winapi

I have subclassed edit control to accept only numbers.

Also, in subclassing procedure, I parse clipboard data to remove forbidden characters.

I have achieved the desired behavior, or at least so I thought, but the only problem is that I can type dot in the edit control as well.

I do not know what is wrong with my code, so I post it here in hope that somebody else can help me.

Clipboard parsing returns proper data, but it is the WM_CHAR that gives me trouble.

Please help, I just can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Thank you.

Here is the code for the subclassing procedure:

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK MyEditProc ( HWND hwnd, 
                                  UINT message, 
                                  WPARAM wParam, 
                                  LPARAM lParam, 
                                  UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, 
                                  DWORD_PTR  dwRefData )
    {
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_PASTE:
              {
                 if ( OpenClipboard( NULL ) ) 
                 {

                     HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);

                     wchar_t *pchData =
                                        (wchar_t*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);

                     GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);

                     CloseClipboard();

                     int i = 0, j = 0;

                     wchar_t *temp = new wchar_t[51]; // parsed string

                     memset( temp, '\0', sizeof(temp) );

                     // integer numbers are parsed here

                     while( ( i < (int)wcslen(pchData) )
                          && ( j < 10 ) ) // I just need first 10
                     {
                         if( isdigit( pchData[i] ) )
                            temp[j++] = pchData[i];
                         i++;
                     }

                     temp[j] = '\0';

                     // replace selection with parsed text

                     SendMessage( hwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 
                                  (WPARAM)TRUE, (LPARAM)temp );

                     // set caret at the end of the text

                     SendMessage( hwnd, EM_SETSEL, j, j );

                     delete[] temp;
                  }
               }
               return TRUE;
               break;

        case WM_CHAR:
               {

                   if( ! ( isdigit(wParam)
                         || wParam == VK_RETURN
                         || wParam == VK_DELETE
                         || wParam == VK_BACK ) 
                         // this check bellow is needed 
                         // so I can catch WM_PASTE !
                         && ( ! ( GetKeyState( VK_CONTROL ) & 0x8000 ) ) ) 
                   {
                         return 0;
                   }
                }
                break;
        }
        return DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

I have subclassed the control on WM_CREATE like this:

```
SetWindowSubclass( hEdit, MyEditProc, 0, 0);
```

Since I didn't passed anything as the 4th parameter to the procedure above, I didn't feel the need to call `RemoveWindowSubclass`.

### EDIT:

Since Mr. Passant pointed at the error in my solution I have deleted it in order to not confuse people who read this post in search for a solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core mistake is that you are testing virtual key codes in the WM_CHAR message handler.  That's incorrect, virtual key codes are only used in the WM_KEYDOWN/UP messages.  WM_CHAR gets the translated keystroke, a character as selected by the active keyboard layout and the keyboard state.  The TranslateMessage() call in your message loop gets that job done.  Using GetKeyState() is similarly wrong, that was already done by TranslateMessage().

You lucked out with VK_RETURN and VK_BACK, those virtual key codes have the same code as the translated control code (0x0d and 0x08).  Luck ran out with VK_DELETE, it has code 0x2e which is the same as the `'.'` character.

Correct code ought to resemble:

```
   case WM_CHAR:
   {
       if (wParam >= ' ' && !isdigit(wParam) {
           return 0;
       }
   }
   break;
```

Comment: A small question: Why do you test wParam if it is greater than space ? I do not understand that part, can you please briefly explain ? Thank you. Regards. P.S. The line of code I meant is this:                if( wParam >= ' '

Comment: You don't want to mess with the control codes.  Like Crl+X, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C, Backspace.  Used to edit and operate the clipboard.  You only care about suppressing real characters, anything >= 0x20. The space character.